# Swift Interstitial Making a Banner Ad?

Tags: swift, admob, banner, interstitial

I recently put Admob interstitial ads in my game. They appear when the player dies and then can be dismissed.

For some reason when the interstitial is dismissed, it creates an admob banner at the bottom of the screen which I can not ever hide. This is a big problem because it covers up the game when the player hits the replay button, and it can also cover up the UI in the store.

I *do* have an Admob banner, but it **only** appears on the menu scene.

- There are 3 scenes, the menu, the game, and the store. In the store and the game's func Update, the admob banner is set to hidden = true. So there is absolutely no way it is the same banner, surely?
- If I put in the func update of store or game print(googlebannerview.hidden) it always says hidden = true, **even though I can see an ad on the bottom of the screen**.

What is causing this? From what I can see the interstitial is either spawning its own banner when it is dismissed, or it is somehow setting the menu banner to be hidden = false and telling it to lie in the console and not be able to be changed.

I don't think showing any code would help so.. please if you have any ideas!

EDIT: if the explanation wasn't that good you can see for yourself, this bug is on the live version of my app. Search Frog Leap on the app store, it's the first one. When you die and then press replay you will notice it makes a banner ad. It also happens if you hit the menu button and go to the store. It never goes away.

Comment: Here is a link to my app so you can easily see the problem.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/frog-leap/id1054643963?ls=1&mt=8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift Admob Interstitial Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37455298/swift-admob-interstitial-error)