# Swift Admob Interstitial Not Properly Dismissing Fully

Tags: ios, swift, admob, interstitial

I just added Admob interstitial ads to my Swift SpriteKit app.
The problem is, when an interstitial ad is dismissed, it seems to make its own banner ad and place it at the bottom of the screen. It won't go away and I can't make it go away.
*I have a banner ad on the menu scene but it only displays on that scene, and using prints I have confirmed it is a different banner.*

The problem banner then blocks the game and vital UI in the store. I need this fixed, it made its way onto the live version of my app so if anyone has any clue what is going on please post.
For reference, if you need to see my app [here is the link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/frog-leap/id1054643963?ls=1&mt=8)
 to it in the app store. (And no, I'm not just posting the link to try and earn $0.01 from advertisements from you.)

Comment: I still desperately need help with this. For some reason when I dismiss an interstitial ad it is making a banner ad at the bottom of the screen that is not ever going away. It is blocking parts of my game and ruining it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift Interstitial Making a Banner Ad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37475218/swift-interstitial-making-a-banner-ad)