# Dismissing Swift Admob Interstitial makes a banner?

Tags: ios, swift, admob, banner, interstitial

in my swift game when I dismiss an admob interstitial it creates a banner at the bottom of the screen that never ever goes away.
It is blocking vital parts of the game and needs to go but I don't know what to do.
I've tried everything possible to reference it or even find out what it is. Printing what node is touched, etc. (When I touch it nothing prints, it's like even the game itself doesn't know what's going on)

Comment: Can you put the code for your interstitial and banner, so i may help you?

Comment: The code for my interstitials is all here. Except it's slightly different now, I incorporated the correct answer's method for calling the interstitial function.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37455298/swift-admob-interstitial-error